# Z3Py: Creating a list of constants of an uninterpreted sort

Tags: z3, z3py

I have an uninterpreted sort A

```
sortA = DeclareSort('A')
```

and a function foo:

```
foo = Function('foo',sortA,sortA,BoolSort())
```

Now I want to define a list of constants of sort A. My try was:

```
X = [ Consts("c_%s" % i,sortA) for i in range(10) ]
```

But this does not work, since

```
s.add(foo(X[0],X[1]))
```

gives a "Z3 expression expected" error. I would be thankful for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Consts` creates a *list* of constants and that list is not a Z3 expression (but a Python list of Z3 expressions). Instead using `Const` works as expected.